# Placing limits on edge of VegaLite map

Tags: plot, julia, vega-lite, cartography

I'm using VegaLite and VegaDatasets to show a Mercator projection of the world map, and plot a point at a specific latitude and longitude.  So far, this works to produce the map:

```
data = DataFrame(x=[-45], y=[35])
scale = 100
world = dataset("world-110m")
@vlplot(width=700, height=500,
    config={
        view={stroke=:transparent}
    }
) +
@vlplot(data={values=world,
              format={type=:topojson,
                      feature="countries",
                     }},
        mark={type=:geoshape,
              stroke=:darkgray,
              strokeWidth=1},
        projection={type=:mercator,
                    scale=scale,
                    center=[0,35]},
    color={value="#eee"}
)
```

producing
[image]

However, when I try to plot the point in the dataframe "data", I'm trying to set the domain in X and Y directions to (-180,180) and (-90,90), respectively:

```
+ @vlplot(data=data,
          :point,
          x = {:x, scale = {domain = (-180,180)}},
          y = {:y, scale = {domain = (-90,90)}},
  )
```

resulting in the following plot, where the domains are not at the edge of the horizontal and vertical axis. Additionally, the point seems to be plotted incorrectly within the defined grid:

[image]

Using the `@vlplot` syntax, how can I properly set up a latitude/longitude grid on my map, and plot a single point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For plotting geoshape and geopoint in VegaLite, you should specify the coordinate by `longitude` and `latitude`. So your last code should be (projection should be included):

```
+ @vlplot(data=data,
          :point,
          longitude = :x,
          latitude = :y,
          projection={type=:mercator,
                    scale=scale,
                    center=[0,35]}
  )
```